# Can I sue my client for not paying?

Tags: contracts, freelance-websites, payment-terms

So, I got a client through Freelancer about a year and a half ago who was not willing to pay me on the site because he said he had an accountant and company process that didn't allow that, but he was willing to sign a contract online.

Since he is in the UK and I am in India, I figured that was the only way. After struggling to pay through PayPal (he said there was fraud committed on that account) and me not having a bank account in the UK, he ended up paying me on Freelancer.

Months after that, he used my services, apologized as he was traveling/facing trouble with the bank/was hospitalized (all the excuses in the book), and even now has not paid me.

The contract has a 14 day payment release clause; can I take legal action in this case? And how would I go about it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is seeking *legal* advice In addition, most crowd-sourcing sites have terms of service regarding this. This is **not** a support community for crowdsource freelancing sites.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, this would be a small claims case.

You have 1 year and 1 day to file against someone who owes you money; in this case, your case would be too old, as this is regulated by Statute of Limitations if you are in the US.

If you got this client on Freelancer, they have a dispute policy, which should be your first call.

Answer (score -1):

1. Yes you can!
2. You find a lawyer who knows about this stuff!

Comment: 3. The lawyer will cost you more than the amount at stake.

Comment: OP did not state the amount in question, but having a lawyer write a stern letter should not cost a fortune. Besides, that was not the OP's question.

Comment: "Threatening to sue is free" - Arrested Development, paraphrased.